# How to fire onProgressChanged () per segment

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on android application and i am facing an optimization problem : I have a `seekbar` whenever the user drags the thumb near the middle (the `max value` is 100 so by near the middle i mean between 55 and 45 ) the thumb should automatically jump to the middle .

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    x=seek.getProgress();
    if (x>45 && x<55) {
        seek.setProgress(50);
    }
    socket.emit("move1", x);
}
```

It works but whenever the thumb jumps the `onProgressChanged` event keeps firing continuously until the user moves the thumb away from the middle area , so this consumes too much resources. What I want is, while the progress of the `seekbar` is between 45 and 55 the `onProgressChanged` fires only once.

Comment: Use the `fromUser` boolean to check if its the user moving the thumb, then, using a flag, set the position, then unset the flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you - The `fromUser` parameter tells you whether the progress changed due to an action from the user or programmatically. If it was changed by the user, and if it is not already at 50, then set it to 50.

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        int x = seekBar.getProgress();
        if(fromUser && x != 50 && x > 45 && x < 55) {
            seekBar.setProgress(50);
        }
        ....
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the effort and sorry for my bad explanation , first of all : i want the thumb jump to happen even while the users finger is on the seekbar , secondly i want the onProgressChanged to run only once in the [45,55] range .